# Why accuracy of tflite model is so different from keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I made a model that predict a character on an image, to do license plate recognition. It works very well on my computer, but I need to put this work in an Android app. So I developped a little application and convert my keras model to tflite. And now it's always predicting the same character.

I converted the model using :

```
mod_path = "License_character_recognition.h5"

def load_model(path,custom_objects={},verbose=0):
    #from tf.keras.models import model_from_json

    path = splitext(path)[0]
    with open('MobileNets_character_recognition.json','r') as json_file:
        model_json = json_file.read()
    model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(model_json, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    model.load_weights('%s.h5' % path)
    if verbose: print('Loaded from %s' % path)
    return model

keras_mod = load_model(mod_path)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(keras_mod)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the TF Lite model.
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('ocr.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

Is there a better way to convert the model, or am I missing something ?

**EDIT :** This is what I did to manage the bitmap

```
        try {
            Mat bis = Utils.loadResource(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.plaque, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_COLOR);
            cvtColor(bis, bis, COLOR_BGR2RGB);

            Mat m = Utils.loadResource(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.plaque,Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

            blur(m, blur, new Size(2,2));

            threshold(blur, bin, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV + THRESH_OTSU);

            ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours;
            contours = getContours(bin);

            //Try to sort from left to right
            Collections.sort(contours, new SortByTopLeft());
            Log.d("Contour", String.valueOf(contours.size()));
            int i = 0;
            for (MatOfPoint c : contours){
                Rect cont = boundingRect(c);
                float ratio = (float) (cont.height/cont.width);
                Log.d("Ratio", String.valueOf(ratio));
                float pourcent =  ((float) cont.height/ (float) bin.height());
                Log.d("pourcent", String.valueOf(pourcent));
                if (ratio >= 1 && ratio <= 2.5){
                    if(pourcent >=0.5){
                        Log.d("Ui", String.valueOf(cont));
                        rectangle(bis, cont, new Scalar(0,255,0), 2);

                        //Separate numbers
                        Mat curr_num = new Mat(bin, cont);
                        Bitmap curbit = Bitmap.createBitmap(curr_num.cols(), curr_num.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        Utils.matToBitmap(curr_num, curbit);
                        images[i].setImageBitmap(curbit);
                        int charac = classifier.classify(curbit);
                        Log.d("Result", String.valueOf(charac));
                        result.setText(String.valueOf(charac));
                        if (i < 6){
                            i++;
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: If you blame android please put android code that does bitmap manipulation to check

Comment: I edited my question if it can help you

Comment: Please read this article https://medium.com/@farmaker47/impact-of-different-image-loading-and-resizing-libraries-in-tensorflow-inference-output-and-df3c96a41825 and see if loading images and manipulate them with tensorflow library can solve your issue...

Comment: Thanks you were right managing image with Tensorflowsupport library was the answer ! I recreated the input and output with this part of your article ```tensorflow_support_library.java```

Comment: Ok nice! I will add an answer and if you can please upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TensorFlow Lite Android Support Library](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support#basic_image_manipulation_and_conversion). This [library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support/tree/master/tensorflow_lite_support/java) is designed to help process the input and output of TensorFlow Lite models, and make the TensorFlow Lite interpreter easier to use.

Use it like below and find more at [this article](https://medium.com/@farmaker47/impact-of-different-image-loading-and-resizing-libraries-in-tensorflow-inference-output-and-df3c96a41825):

```
    Bitmap assetsBitmap = getBitmapFromAsset(mContext, "picture.jpg");
    // Initialization code
    // Create an ImageProcessor with all ops required. For more ops, please
    // refer to the ImageProcessor Architecture.
    ImageProcessor imageProcessor =
            new ImageProcessor.Builder()
                    .add(new ResizeOp(32, 32, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
                    //.add(new NormalizeOp(127.5f, 127.5f))
                    .build();

    // Create a TensorImage object. This creates the tensor of the corresponding
    // tensor type (flot32 in this case) that the TensorFlow Lite interpreter needs.
    TensorImage tImage = new TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32);

    // Analysis code for every frame
    // Preprocess the image
    tImage.load(assetsBitmap);
    tImage = imageProcessor.process(tImage);

    // Create a container for the result and specify that this is not a quantized model.
    // Hence, the 'DataType' is defined as FLOAT32
    TensorBuffer probabilityBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 10}, DataType.FLOAT32);
    interpreter.run(tImage.getBuffer(), probabilityBuffer.getBuffer());

    Log.i("RESULT", Arrays.toString(probabilityBuffer.getFloatArray()));

    return getSortedResult(result);
}
```