# TFlite Android bytebuffer creation for inference

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite, inference

I have a customly trained mobilenetV2 model which accepts as input a 128x101x3 array of FLOAT32.
In Android (Java), when calling the tflite model inference, the float[x][y][z] input must be converted into a bytebuffer of size 4*128*101*3 (4 for the float size and the rest for the image size).

The problem is that I there are many ways to make the conversion and I cannot find which is the right one. I can think to add to the bytebuffer fist all the z for each x and y, or I can add all the y for each x and for each z.

For example, let's suppose for sake of simplicity that the 3rd dimension is just a repetition, i.e. [x][y][0] == [x][y][1] == [x][y][2]. Now I can create the bytebuffer like this:

```
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 128 * 101 * 3);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<myArray[0].length; j++){
                byteBuffer.putFloat(myArray[i][j]); // z=0
                byteBuffer.putFloat(myArray[i][j]); // z=1
                byteBuffer.putFloat(myArray[i][j]); // z=2
            }
        }
    byteBuffer.rewind();
```

Or I can create a bytebuffer like this:

```
    for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
            int [] inpShapeDim = {1, 1, myArray[0].length, 1};
            TensorBuffer valInTnsrBuffer = TensorBuffer.createDynamic(imageDataType); // imageDataType = FLOAT32
            valInTnsrBuffer.loadArray(myArray[i], inpShapeDim); //inpShapeDim=1x128x101x3
            byteBuffer.put(valInTnsrBuffer.getBuffer());
        }
        int oneDeltaBufferPosition = byteBuffer.position();
        for (int z=0; z<2; deltas++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < oneDeltaBufferPosition; i++) {
                byteBuffer.put(byteBuffer2.get(i));
            }
        }
        byteBuffer.rewind();
```

Both of them are "valid" conversions, but then the inference doesn't work as expected, meaning that the recognition accuracy is not the same as in python.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You shoud check the [TensorFlow Lite Android Support Library](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support#basic_image_manipulation_and_conversion)

Or you can check to [the answer of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63726309/why-accuracy-of-tflite-model-is-so-different-from-keras-model) following his instruction I eventually got nice results